# Is injectivity of algebras preserved by tensor products?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, tensor-products

> Suppose $R' \subset R$, $S'\subset S$ are inclusion of $k$-algebras. Does it hold that $R'\otimes_kS' \rightarrow R \otimes_k S$ is injective ?

I know there're counterexamples for modules, but why does the algebra make things different?

I found it used as a lemma in the Stacks project to prove [Lemma `00I3`](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00I3).

Comment: All $k$-modules are free :)

Comment: In this text, Is k a commutative ring only, or is it a field? In the likely event it's a field, do you see how Alex's tip solves your question?

Comment: @rschwieb At least in the text referred to by OP, $k$ is a field.

Comment: @AlexYoucis Thanks: I haven't found the opportunity to peruse their resources yet :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, $R'\otimes_kS' \rightarrow R \otimes_k S$ needn't be injective: here is a counterexample.

Take $k=\mathbb Z$, $R'=\mathbb Z\hookrightarrow R=\prod_{n=1}^\infty  \mathbb Z/2^n \mathbb Z$ the unique morphism,  and $S'= \mathbb Z/3 \mathbb Z \stackrel {id}{\to} S=\mathbb Z/3 \mathbb Z $.

Then the morphism $R'\otimes_k S'=\mathbb Z/3\mathbb Z \rightarrow R \otimes_k S=0$ is not injective because its source is non-zero and its target is zero.

[The equality $ R \otimes_k S=R\otimes _\mathbb Z \mathbb Z/3\mathbb Z=R/3R=0$ follows from the fact that $3$ is invertible in $R=\prod_{n=1}^\infty  \mathbb Z/2^n \mathbb Z$ since it is invertible in all the factors $\mathbb Z/2^n \mathbb Z$]

Comment: Note though that for the OP, $k$ is a field :)

Comment: Dear @Alex: I know (I read the comments), but   I wanted to know whether there is  a counterexample with $k$ a ring. Let's say it was a challenge to myself.