# $A \to A \otimes_{k} l$ is injective for $k$-algebra $A$ and field extension $l/k$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

Let $l/k$ be a field extension, and $A$ a $k$-algebra, then the tensor product
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
k @>>> l\\
@VVV @VVV\\
A @>>> A \otimes_{k} l
\end{CD}
giving an injective map $A\to A\otimes_{k} l$?

Vaguely, I think that it's from $A$ is the same as some $k[A]/I$, and $A \otimes_{k} l$ is the same as $l[A]/I$ and $k[A]/I \to l[A]/I$ is injective. But I cannot make it rigorous. If $A$ is finitely generated, the argument seems easier. But generally, I don't know how to say it. And must this result use the idea presenting $A$ as the quotient ring of a (maybe infinite many indeterminants) polynomials ring on $k$? Is it some easier proof? Is the comment "every $k$-module is free module" in the linked thread a hint?

And I got a counterexample from [Is injectivity of algebras preserved by tensor products?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/509785/is-injectivity-of-algebras-preserved-by-tensor-products) that

\begin{CD}
\Bbb{Z} @>>> \bigoplus_{n=1}^{\infty} \Bbb{Z}/2^n \Bbb{Z}\\
@VVV @VVV\\
\Bbb{Z}/3\Bbb{Z} @>>> 0
\end{CD}

fails to be injective. Why does it failed in the general case of algebras over a ring? It seems it still be able to present $\Bbb{Z}/3\Bbb{Z}$ some quotient of a polynomial ring of $\Bbb{Z}$.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: A free modules $M$ is in particular flat, i.e. tensoring with $M$ is exact. Therefore, as all $k$-modules are free, tensoring the injection $k\to l$ with $A$ gives again an injection.

Comment: It's very elegant and consise. Thankyou @imtrying46